# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is the appsetting.json file

```
{
  "Connection Strings": {
    "EmployeeDBConnection": "server=(localhost)\\SQLEXPRESS ; database=EmployeeDB; Trusted_Connection =true"
  },


  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },


  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MyKey": "Value of MYKey from appsettings.json"

}
```

This is the startup.cs file

```
namespace EmployeeManagement
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;

      
        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;

        }
        
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, SQLEmployeeRepository>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection")));
       

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
               
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World");
            });


        }
     
    }

}
```

I have checked that "Connection Strings" has s in the end,
Changed the placement of the connection strings in the appsetting.json file
Instead of just writing the name of the connection string in Configuration.GetConnectionString() in Startup.cs, I put the entire ConnectionString there
I am still having this error.

Comment: "Connection Strings" is not a valid key for json. use  "ConnectionStrings" instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key `"Connection Strings"` contains space. Change to `"ConnectionStrings"` for the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`"Connection Strings"` does not match your parameter `"connectionStrings"`. You need to change that in appsettings.cs. It could also need to be `"connectionString"` instead, I am a bit confused by your wording. Regardless, your program is looking for `"connectionString"`, not `"Connection Strings"`.